# how to make HTTP GET specific data in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-get, blazor-webassembly

I had created a controller HttpGet to get specific user data, but when I call the API in client side, it doesn't show the results.

Controller

```
[HttpGet("{Id}/{Username}")]
public ApplicationUser Details(string Id, string Username)
{
  return _dataAccessProvider.GetAspNetUsersSingleRecord(Id, Username);
}
```

Client side call API by HttpGet

```
@code {
    private UserProfile[] forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<UserProfile[]>("Authentication/ed131c76-4a3a-4626-aec5-3db534f14a30/amrita");
    }
}
```

GetAspNetUsersSingleRecord

```
public ApplicationUser GetAspNetUsersSingleRecord(string Id, string Username)
{
     return _context.applicationUser.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == Id &&  t.UserName == Username);
}
```

Got this error

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: The JSON value could not be converted to BlazorWebAssemblyFrontEnd.Pages.UserProfile[].
> Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted
> to BlazorWebAssemblyFrontEnd.Pages.UserProfile[]. Path: $ |
> LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.   at
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue
> (System.Type propertyType) <0x30082d0 + 0x00032> in :0    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2[TCollection,TElement].OnTryRead (System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader& reader, System.Type typeToConvert, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options, System.Text.Json.ReadStack& state, TCollection& value) <0x3005988 + 0x001de> in <filename unknown>:0    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[T].TryRead
> (System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader& reader, System.Type typeToConvert,
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options,
> System.Text.Json.ReadStack& state, T& value) <0x3005008 + 0x0029a> in
> :0    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[T].ReadCore (System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader& reader, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options, System.Text.Json.ReadStack& state) <0x30048a8 + 0x00292> in <filename unknown>:0    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue] (System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter jsonConverter, System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader& reader, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options, System.Text.Json.ReadStack& state) <0x2ff9b20 + 0x0002a> in <filename unknown>:0    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[TValue] (System.Text.Json.JsonReaderState& readerState, System.Boolean isFinalBlock, System.ReadOnlySpan`1[T] buffer,
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options,
> System.Text.Json.ReadStack& state,
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter converterBase) <0x2ff99e8
>
> - 0x00058> in :0    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadAsync[TValue] (System.IO.Stream
>   utf8Json, System.Type returnType,
>   System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x2ff3d68 +
>   0x0033c> in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () <0x309b428 + 0x00034> in <filename unknown>:0    at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsyncCore[T] (System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, System.Text.Encoding sourceEncoding, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x2fedb48 + 0x00218> in <filename unknown>:0    at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.GetFromJsonAsyncCore[T] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] taskResponse,
>   System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x2f62e50 +
>   0x001d2> in :0    at
>   BlazorWebAssemblyFrontEnd.Pages.Profile.OnInitializedAsync ()
>   [0x00033] in
>   C:\Users\yaps\source\repos\BlazorWebAssemblyFrontEnd\Pages\Profile.razor:44
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync
>   () <0x2c866d8 + 0x0013a> in :0    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task taskToHandle) <0x2f09b70 + 0x000b6> in
>   :0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client expect another response from the server. The client side expect a array (a sort list) and the server side returned a single object.

I would expect this:

```
private UserProfile forecasts;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<UserProfile>("Authentication/ed131c76-4a3a-4626-aec5-3db534f14a30/amrita");
}
```

The properties need to match to get the data in the object of UserProfile. Otherwise some of the properties will be empty.

A good practice would be to create a shared project with the client and the server side with the possible responses and requests. Then you should have a less chance to get a mismatch.

Comment: BTW: If you use the ApplicationUser from Entity framework, then you shouldn't return the ApplicationUser. Because in the ApplicationUser, there is a password field with the hash of the password. You never return the hash of the password to a client. But I cannot see which properties you have in ApplicationUser. So, I cannot judge that.

Comment: Hi Oscar, I am using IdentityUser for ApplicationUser.

Comment: Hi Leafrain. My comment was more een advise. But your solution is in my answer. I hope you can fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and advises, gratitude! Currently, I am doing a Blazor WebAssembly PWA by calling a Web API from different project. The API is built by .NET Core act as server side. I am totally new for this, and still learning on it.

Comment: Do you have any advise for login? Do I need to use HttpClient to do login or have other ways..

Comment: Please read the following documentation from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0. Maybe it helps. Otherwise you can always create another question here on stackoverflow. (If you don't find the answer.)

Comment: Hi, @Oscar I have another question, can you please help me have a look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238729/how-to-covert-json-result-into-string-in-blazor-webassembly